# Why does my SSH Known Hosts have hashes instead of hostnames or IPs?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a host behind a dynamic IP, so I used to have a script that would add its address to my .ssh/known_hosts file, recently though it seems like something has changed. My file looks like its been attacked by the hash monster:

```
|1|Du0QWjqCUrdRK/pnE0PTww2O2Zk=|O31W+SPPLr9+sj1m1K7MfEb+xUQ= ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILUT1234567Xu2vvCE1likgUSOXLzEV123456783asaA
|1|K3vgE86MLJTHx8W2sPv1cgP4DI0=|Jattsr5sEW443bnyMKT6W0Noc+k= ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILUT1234567Xu2vvCE1likgUSOXLzEV123456783asaA
|1|UlAukzqGavXZvRtMzjvXmHoVeAQ=|0JVjq7YSFulCHmkF46VFwMV/ZBY= ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILUT1234567Xu2vvCE1likgUSOXLzEV123456783asaA
```

1. Is there anyway to go back to the old, less secure method?
2. How can I easily create entries in this hashed format? (I want to write a script to tell ssh that any ip in the 10.0.0.0/24 range is should match the given fingerprint.)

Comment: Note that this is a security feature to prevent information disclosure (namely, to make it difficult for someone who gets a hold of your known hosts file to figure out what systems you’ve connected to, which in turn makes it harder for an attacker that0s compromised one system to compromise others you have access to).

Comment: _"I have a host behind a dynamic IP ..."_ - Have you considered setting up DNS (perhaps with something like dyndns) for that host? That would be easier to use in general, and not require updating known_hosts.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable the hostname hashing by setting the `HashKnownHosts` SSH client option to "no": either each time on the command line (`ssh -o HashKnownHosts=no ...`) or in your user configuration file `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host *
  HashKnownHosts no
```

Not sure how you can hash a hostname yourself, but you can have intermixed entries in the `known_hosts` file, hashed and non-hashed ones, so it would be fine for your script to create non-hashed entries.

And you could use `ssh-keygen -H` to convert all entries in the `known_hosts` file to their hashed form.

Comment: One can also add `HashKnownHosts = no` in the user's `.ssh/config` file for each connection to overwrite the system-wide setting

Answer (score 10):

> How can I easily create entries in this hashed format?

You don't say how exactly you are currently adding the key to the known hosts file, but I am going to assume that you are using [`ssh-keyscan`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan), since that is the tool which is specifically designed for this exact use case:

> `ssh-keyscan` is a utility for gathering the public SSH host keys of a number of hosts. It was designed to aid in building and verifying *ssh_known_hosts* files, the format of which is documented in [sshd(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8). `ssh-keyscan` provides a minimal interface suitable for use by shell and perl scripts.

So, I assume your script currently contains a line like this:

```sh
# Delete the entry for the old IP
ssh-keygen -R $OLD_IP

# Add entry for the new IP
ssh-keyscan $NEW_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

All you need to do is the add the [`-H` flag](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keyscan#H) to generate the output in the hashed format:

```sh
ssh-keyscan -H $NEW_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

> (I want to write a script to tell ssh that any ip in the 10.0.0.0/24 range is should match the given fingerprint.)

I believe that could be achieved in a much simpler way.

SSH has a [`KnownHostsCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#KnownHostsCommand) configuration parameter which allows you to specify a command that outputs host key lines in the same format as the known hosts file. This command will be called after SSH has read the known hosts files and allows you to add additional entries on the fly, based on the information of the current connection attempt.

So, you could put something like this in your SSH configuration file:

```
Host 10.0.0.*
  KnownHostsCommand /usr/bin/env printf "%H ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILUT1234567Xu2vvCE1likgUSOXLzEV123456783asaA"
```

[I am using the `/usr/bin/env` trick here because SSH requires the path to the `KnownHostsCommand` to be absolute and the path for `printf` is not standardized. You can use the absolute path to `printf` on your system instead if you want to.]

So, what this means is: if the host you are trying to connect to matches the [*pattern*](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#pattern) `10.0.0.*`, then add the result of calling the following command to the list of host keys. The command, in turn, uses the [*token*](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS) `%H` (meaning "the host name we are trying to look up") and the string from your question to construct a valid known hosts key line for whatever IP address you are currently trying to connect to.

No need to litter your known hosts file with 254 identical entries.

Comment: The current method for adding hosts is simple really: I ssh into the machine, and it asks me if I want to add it as known. :P

Comment: @fny Hahaha.  "Security until it hurts" is the new slogan.